SwiftUI List selection behaviour Preview vs Simulator
I am having trouble understanding why SwiftUI list selection behaviour is different between the Previews and the actual app running when pushing a detail view.
Here is the app view
import SwiftUI

@main
struct SwiftUIListApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ListView()
        }
    }
}

and here is my simple list
import SwiftUI

struct ListItem: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let title: String
    var id: String { title }
}

@Observable
final class ListViewModel {
    private(set) var items: [ListItem] = []
    
    @MainActor func loadData() async {
        items = (1...100).map { ListItem(title: "\($0)") }
    }
}

struct ListView: View {
    @State private var viewModel = ListViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                ForEach(viewModel.items) { item in
                    NavigationLink(value: item) {
                        Text(item.title)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("SwiftUI List")
            .navigationDestination(for: ListItem.self) { item in
                ListDetailView(item: item)
            }
        }
        .task {
            await viewModel.loadData()
        }
    }
}

struct ListDetailView: View {
    let item: ListItem
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Detail view \(item.title)")
            .navigationTitle("Detail")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    }
}

#Preview {
    ListView(viewModel: ListViewModel())
}

When I select a row in the preview, the row gets selected and the detail view is pushed. When I navigate back to the list the row gets de-selected when the list view appears. This is similar behaviour to UITableViewController and is exactly what I want. (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcontroller/1614758-clearsselectiononviewwillappear)
However when I run the app in the simulator/device, the row gets deselected immediately before the push. The list view itself does not seem to re-draw because scroll position is maintained correctly.

Note, you could just use var viewModel: ListViewModel in your ListView.

thanks for the message and the tip. Yeah true because it's injected, however it's merely for demonstration purposes so should hopefully not make a difference.

State should always be private, State is a source of truth and makes a deep copy of Observable

Managed to figure out the issue in the end and posted an answer. Thanks again for the help.

Thanks as well for the State tip, this was more of a copy and paste thing and me playing around with the new @Observable macro. I have updated the question.

Found the solution after playing around with Apples demo app https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/bringing_robust_navigation_structure_to_your_swiftui_app
Added this to the view model
var itemPaths: [ListItem] = []

And updated the NavigationStack
NavigationStack(path: $viewModel.itemPaths) { ... }

Still not sure why the preview behaves differently but I take it.

It is usually the Preview that is broken, and in this case, you don't control the selection with a selection: parameter, so it is reasonable that the List doesn't track its selection.
To make the List selectable, do:
@State var selection: ListItem?
var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
        List(selection: $selection) {
            ...
        }
        .navigationDestination(item: $selection) { item in
            ListDetailView(item: item)
        }
    }
}

Note that I have changed this to use navigationDestination(item:destination:). If you would like to track navigation with a navigation path, it is less convenient, but still doable.
@State var navigationPath: [ListItem] = []
var body: some View {
    NavigationStack(path: $navigationPath) {
        List(selection: $navigationPath[safe: 0]) {

where the [safe:] subscript is:
extension MutableCollection where Self: RangeReplaceableCollection {
    subscript(safe i: Index) -> Element? {
        get { indices.contains(i) ? self[i] : nil }
        set {
            if let newValue {
                if indices.contains(i) {
                    self[i] = newValue
                } else {
                    self.insert(newValue, at: i)
                }
            } else {
                remove(at: i)
            }
        }
    }
}


hey, thank you very much for your answer, I have actually manage to figure it out. See my answer above.
